# Query Mongo collection for all items with field "info" containing the string "New"

Tags: mongodb

I am looking for the best way to query mongo where the field info can be searched
based on string value.
**Example:**
db.items.find({$someOperation:{"info":"N"}}) will return all the items in the collection that has field info and value which includes "N" (case insensitive)

Comment: `db.items.find({ "info": /^N$/i })`

or

`db.items.find( { info: /N/i } );`

Same thing.

Comment: Should the /^N$/i be in quotes or nah?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be in quotes.

Comment: Is there a way to create this query in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Use [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) with "i" (case insensitivity) option.

```
db.collection.find({info: {$regex: "n", $options: "i"  }})
```